# How much energy would the Human Torch need?

Tags: thermodynamics

I wasn't sure whether to put this in the SciFi section or here, but since I'm interested in a physical quantity,so I decided to ask it here. I was wondering about approximately how much energy would the Human Torch need to reach X temperature. I was wondering if $Q=mC\Delta T$ would be useful, but I'm not sure if there's such thing as a $C$ for human skin?

Comment: You'd be surprised at what exists: http://www.itis.ethz.ch/itis-for-health/tissue-properties/database/heat-capacity/

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful indeed. But now I wonder if I were to calculate a simple approximation, it doesn't have to be really accurate—— would I take the mass of the average person and use only the $C$ for skin?

Comment: Joke's on you, The Human Torch is pretty far from being human.

Comment: You don't have to take the mass of the average person, Human Torch [weighs 170 lbs](http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_%28Johnny_Storm%29). :P

Comment: Note that in canon, the flame does not actually touch the skin, it is separated by a very thin layer of air (which is why he doesn't get burned).  Also note that, according to Wikipedia, it is not just flame, but *plasma* that envelops him, which would take a lot more energy than just ordinary fire.

Comment: So basically I can't calculate an approximation of how much energy does he need? I'm not really an expert in thermodynamics and now that you mention it's plasma that envelops him, I'm not too sure how to proceed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much oxygen would be consumed on a 1 cm squared surface which is on fire?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23007/)

Comment: Jerson, the title of question I linked doesn't look related, but the question is actually about the Human Torch.

Comment: I was looking at it, and yeah it sort of helps a bit. I was just wondering if I could do a quick calculation since I need it for a project in Physics. But it's supposed to be based on mechanical physics, that's why I asked if the equation above would be okay for a rough approximation.