# How much oxygen is required to maintain a constant temperature (400 C) in a BBQ Smoker?

Tags: thermodynamics

I would like to calculate the amount of oxygen required to maintain a constant temperature of 400 degrees Celsius inside the firebox (oak wood) of a BBQ Smoker.

I found a similar calculation for the Human Torch ([How much oxygen would be consumed on a 1 cm squared surface which is on fire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/how-much-oxygen-would-be-consumed-on-a-1-cm-squared-surface-which-is-on-fire)) would this method work? If so could someone please advise.

Comment: to answer this, I would need to know how fast the heat is lost to the surroundings. Can you heat up the bbq to 400 degrees and then tell me how much heat is lost after 30 seconds or a minute? Also, I would need an approximate mass of metal that you are heating up, then I can give a full answer to the question